# origin destination as driven by car/truck path on a folium map

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

1. I am trying to plot a path from an origin to destination on a folium map using python.
2. Instead of the usual polyline , is it possible to show the 'as driven by path' (car/truck) from an origin to destination point in a folium map ?
   (something similar to google maps)

Comment: Can you share your relevant code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try PolyLine, to draw polyline overlays on your map

```
folium.PolyLine((lat,long)).add_to(your_map)
```